# WCF Service object serialization

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, inheritance

I have one abstract class named contact and another class called client that inherits from contact. I'm dealing with a WCF Service with a method that takes a parameter of type contact.
however what I have is an instance of client that I want to pass.
Im facing this Error:

> Type 'xxx.Client' with data contract name 'Client:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxx' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF does not directly works on abstract classes. You shall use KnownType attributes on the datacontract or service class. below are examples;

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Client))]
public class Contact
{
   ...
}

[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Client))]
public interface IMyService
{
    contact getcontact(Guid id);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you ned to let DataContractSerializer know that a `Client` is a type of `Contact`.

There are several ways to do this, but they all revolve around using the [`KnownType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) attribute or the [`ServiceKnownType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) attributes.

The `KnownType` can be placed on the `Client` class to tell DataContractSerializer that it is a KnownType of `Contact`.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Client))]
public class Contact{}
```

The `KnownType` can also be placed on a class to indicate that when serialising this class you may also encounter this other class.

You may want to do this if you have a `DataContract` class that has a property which is a `Contact` which may actually contain a `Client`:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Client))]
public class Meeting
{
    Contact MeetingContact{get;}
}
```

In this case you could get away without specifying the KnownType on the Client.  You may also want to do this if you have a property which returns a collection and you want to specify the types which can  be in the collection.

You may, instead of specifying the actual type of the KnownType, specify the name of a static method which will return the known types instead:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public class Meeting
{
    Contact MeetingContact{get;}

    private static Type[] GetKnownType()
    {
    return new Type[]{typeof(Client)};
    }
}
```

You can also specify the known type through the [configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409497/how-to-add-service-known-types-from-external-config-file).

ServiceKnownTypes work in a similar way, but are specified on the Service itself:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Client))]
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IMyServiceContract
{

    [OperationContract]
    Contact GetContact();
}
```

This set up will let  the DataContactSerializer know that any of the methods may return a type of type `Client`.  In a similar way to the known types you can also use a static method to provide the service known types.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [[KnownType]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) and [[ServiceKnownType]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) attributes to ensure the relationships.